# Compute Engine Instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created a Google Compute Engine instance with CentOS and added some stuff there, such as Apache, Webmin, ActiveCollab, Gitolite etc.. etc.
The problem is that the VM is always running out of memory because the RAM is too low.
How do I change the assigned RAM in Google Compute Engine?

Should I have to copy the VM to another with bigger RAM? If so will it copy all the contents from my CentOS installation?

Can anyone give me some advises on how to get more RAM without having to reinstall everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended approach for manually managed instances is to boot from a [Persistent root Disk](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#rootfrompd). When your instance has been booted from Persistent Disk, you can delete the instance and immediately create a new instance from the same disk with a larger machine type. This is similar to shutting down a physical machine, installing faster processors and more RAM, and starting it back up again. This doesn't work with scratch disks because they come and go with the instance.

Using Persistent Disks also enables [snapshots](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#snapshots), which allow you to take a point-in-time snapshot of the exact state of the disk and create new disks from it. You can use them as backups. Snapshots are also global resources, so you can use them to create Persistent Disks in any zone. This makes it easy to migrate your instance between zones (to prepare for a maintenance window in your current zone, for example).

Never store state on scratch disks. If the instance stops for any reason, you've lost that data. For manually configured instances, boot them from a Persistent Disk. For application data, store it on Persistent Disk, or consider using a managed service for state, like [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/) or [Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/).